# .addClass with IF statement based on value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying use an if statement and TWO .addClass background-color variables based on whether the column value for 'shift_times'= "SAT AM/SUN PM" or = "SAT PM/SUN AM". I am finding solutions for when a value is a number, but not text.

```
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(confirmed) as cnt, 
     position, shift_times 
     FROM volConfirm 
     WHERE confirmed='yes'  
     GROUP BY shift_times, position
     order by position"; 

     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['position'] ." ". $row['shift_times'] ."= " . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you were looking for?

```
$query = "SELECT
      COUNT(confirmed) as cnt, 
      position,
      shift_times 
   FROM volConfirm 
   WHERE confirmed='yes'  
   GROUP BY shift_times, position
   ORDER BY position"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ($row['shift_times'] === 'SAT AM/SUN PM') {
      echo '<tr class="class1">';
   } else if ($row['shift_times'] === 'SAT PM/SUN AM') {
      echo '<tr class="class2">';
   } else {
      echo '<tr>';
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['position'] ." ". $row['shift_times'] ."= " . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Ah! It's a thing of beauty! I always my "while if else/if"s confused... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were looking for a jQuery answer based off the content of your question and the fact that `addClass` is a jQuery function... I apologize if I'm wrong. Here's your answer if that's what you meant:

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] ." <span class='shifttimes'>". $row['shift_times'] ."</span>= " . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $.each($('.shifttimes'), function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text() == "SAT AM/SUN PM" ? $this.addClass('className') : $this.addClass('otherClassName');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would JQuery get involved at all? Seems it would be far easier to do with strictly PHP.

Comment: In retrospect, that would make far more sense :-D I banged my head against the wall for ten minutes trying to figure out what addClass was in PHP rather than addressing the direct issue

Comment: I too thought I needed to use JQuery-- maybe :)